# Perl why does the regex substitution work only on the last line?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with mulptiple lines where I try to perfom a calculation on the last number. Here is my code

```
open(FH,"<sample.txt") or die "Can't open that file\n";
       while ($line=<FH>) {
        chomp $line;
        $line=~s/\d+$/$&+5000/eg;
        print $line, "\n";

    }
```

The data looks smth like this

```
    Mark:1/12/68:1000
Ann:2/13/49:5000
Joe:7/25/73:300
```

In the output only last line is modified and the rest stay the same. Anybody has a clue why?

Comment: Not without seeing the data, no.  My first guess would be that your data has whitespace at the end of the lines so that `/\d+$/` doesn't match.

Comment: if you use `$`, it doesn't make sense to have `g`.

Comment: Works for me. Is that really all of your code?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yes, except for the part where I load the file into FH

Comment: chomp => `$line =~ s/\s+\z//`

Comment: I tried to change code to $line=~s/\d+\n$/$&+5000/eg; so that the new line is also substituted but then it doesn't work at all

Comment: @AwPa Why did you take that out? The code and input file you've shown aren't sufficient to reproduce your problem. Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the problem and edit it into your question.

Comment: Please don't show data that "looks smth like this".  Give us actual data.  Also, check for whitespace like my original comment mentioned.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Now the code is exactly the code i have. Thanks for the remark

Comment: @AwPa Again, that's not sufficient to reproduce the problem. Rename your existing files, copy and paste the code and input from this question into two new files, save them with the same names as the original files, and run them. The code works fine (although it could be improved, as Andy Lester points out). You probably have whitespace at the end of the lines in your file that you don't realize is there.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot You are so right! It was white spaces at the end. The solution $line=~s/\d+\s*\z/$&+5000000000/eg;

Comment: Andy Lester wins the prize for [pointing that out 15 minutes ago!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288018/perl-why-does-the-regex-substitution-work-only-on-the-last-line#comment46773315_29288018)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really should be doing is treating your structured data as structured data.

You've got data like this:

```
Mark:1/12/68:1000
Ann:2/13/49:5000
Joe:7/25/73:300
```

and you want to add 5000 to the 3rd field in each row, so do this:

```
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split( /:/, $line );
    $fields[2] += 5000;
    say join( ':', @fields );
}
```

Using `s///e` to increment a numeric value in a field is like stirring paint with a screwdriver.  You can do it, but it's not the most sensible way to do it.